# JSON url to link

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using the google news API and I want to add the value of the URL to be on the article title and convert the image from the JSON data to be viewable. Below is my code so far.

```
/*$.getJSON(url, function(data){
      console.log(data);
  });*/

$.ajax({
    url:
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?apiKey=xxx&q=nrcs",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {


        $(data.articles).each(function (index, value) {
            //console.log(value);        
            $('#news').append('<div>' + '<h3 id="title" style="color:#B8860B;">' + value.title + '' + value.url + '</h3>' + '<p>' + '<span style="color:#C4BFBF; font-style: italic;">' + value.author + '</span>' + '<br>' + value.publishedAt + '<br>' + value.description + '</p>' + '</div>');
            $('#link').append(value.url);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work? How should the result be? Which error messages do you get in the console? Why do you post your private api key on a public forum?

Answer (score 0):

Judging just by this and not seeing the whole picture (returned Json, css styles and layout of the page; basically any conflicting factors) I’d try:

```
$.ajax({
    url:
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?apiKey=xxx&q=nrcs",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {


        $(data.articles).each(function (index, value) {
            //console.log(value);        
            $('#news').append('<div>' + '<h3 id="title" style="color:#B8860B;">' + value.title + '' + value.url + '</h3>' + '<p>' + '<span style="color:#C4BFBF; font-style: italic;">' + value.author + '</span>' + '<br>' + value.publishedAt + '<br>' + value.description + '</p>' + '<br>' + value.url + '</div>');
        });
    }
});
```

Instead of appending to the appended div, add it direct within; check the console for any errors and if there are none your issue may be related to the container / style of your page.

Comment: Thank you it works now, I have put the <h3> into an a tag linking to the value.url and it worked fine